# TransactionTooLargeException when try ro pick image from gallery

Tags: android, kotlin

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
intent.type = "image/*"
val mimeTypes = arrayOf("image/jpeg")
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes)
startActivityForResult(intent, Config.REQUEST_CODE_PICK_IMAGE)
```

Here is my code to start activity and choose image.. immediately after selecting some app (Gallery, Google Photos) I get an exception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 2315820 bytes
        at android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions$StopInfo.run(PendingTransactionActions.java:160)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6694)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 2315820 bytes
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:1129)
        at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.activityStopped(IActivityManager.java:4027)
        at android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions$StopInfo.run(PendingTransactionActions.java:144)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6694) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
2019-10-10 13:51:27.649 20015-20015/am.lsoft.dev.lsmobilebanking.lsoft E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 2315820 bytes
        at android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions$StopInfo.run(PendingTransactionActions.java:160)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6694)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 2315820 bytes
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:1129)
        at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.activityStopped(IActivityManager.java:4027)
        at android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions$StopInfo.run(PendingTransactionActions.java:144)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6694) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

In my device I have ~3000 photos, so I think the problem is in max parcelable size of 1MB
So question, is there any way to handle this issue

Comment: And without the extra mime types?

Comment: Yes, without extra types the result is same.. also the result is same with Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT... I try to use 5 or 6 libraries to do this job, and every time result is same

Comment: Very strange, very uncommon. So the user only selected an app. But not yet an image?

Comment: Yea, only selecting the app is initialize crash.. Also I noticed other strange situation.. If I do this from Activity, it's worked fine.. but if I do this from fragments, crash occurs

Comment: Try to use the Activity context of the fragment.

Comment: Since this is coming via `activityStopped()`, my guess is that you have too much data in your saved instance state `Bundle`.

Comment: CommonsWare Thanks a lot.. the problem is that I have base64 encoded image in arguments.. after removing it, the problem solved

Answer (score 3):

I solved this issue by overriding onSaveInstanceState method

```
 @Override
  public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.clear();
  }
```

It is due to a lot of data in our saved instance bundle